# How can I conditionally set the font size of an element, only if the parents font size is not explicitly set (i.e. font-size is 'inherit')?

Tags: css

```
<div>
  <p>
    Hello
  </p>
</div>
```

How to set `<p>`s font-size to 14px only if `<div>`s font-size is not set (i.e. is `font-size:inherit`)?

Comment: @Paulie_D What about `:has()` and / or attribute selectors ?

Comment: @OBIWAHN the has selector has nothing to do with the css of a parent, merely whether the parent exists not what css it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS variables maybe:

```css
div {
  font-size: var(--f);
}
div p {
  font-size: var(--f,14px);
}
/* if --f is set both will have the same font (similar to inherit)
   if not, the 14px will be used as fallback
*/
```

```html
<div style="--f: 20px">
  <p>
    Hello
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
    Hello
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sneaky, I like it.

Comment: Although,  *technically,* this is setting the font size of the div but it's an elegant solution.

Comment: In my scenario, `p` is within a component, so I need this to work if the font-size of `div` is set manually by the user (e.g. `style="font-size:20px`)

Comment: @Obiwahn add such information into your question. If you want accurate answers you need to clearly define your use case and not give us a generic use case where a lot of answers may apply